# Eclipse Unresolved Inclusion of Boost

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, eclipse-cdt

The Eclipse version is 20130614-0229, Kepler. OS X 10.9.

Boost installed through Macports.

I understand that this question is really old, but after I searched through a dozen of forum pages I am still not able to get them resolved.

[image]

[image]

How to get the boost include files (also the igraph include file) resolved?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out my problem can be solved by tweaking the options in  "Project properties->C/C++ general->Indexer" panel. Please refer to the figure.

First, I checked the "Enable project specific settings". And then, in the indexer options, I checked "Index unused headers as C++ files" and "Index source and header files opened in editor". Finally, I clicked "apply" and "OK" and after a while, all the "bugs" and "unresolved xxx" disappeared.

I'm not sure whether what I did is necessary or sufficient. Also, it always takes some time for the indexer to take effect after I checked or unchecked some options, so I don't have time to find out necessary and sufficient options to solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: It takes a while until changes have an effect because the indexer needs some time to rebuild your index.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your boost installation is not at `/opt/local/include`. Quite possible it is located at something like

`/opt/local/var/macports/software/boost/1.53.0_0/opt/local/boost`

If you have root access, you can do something like

```
cd /opt/local/include
sudo ln -s  /opt/local/var/macports/software/boost/1.53.0_0/opt/local/boost
```

See similar solution(s) [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/lounge/26869/)

Comment: I have just checked, all the boost include files are in `/opt/local/include/boost`.

Comment: Thanks. I can definitely tell that last two paths in your settings are not needed. Please, check again the path, say, to file version.hpp. You should find it at {some path}/boost/version.hpp. Then {some path} should be set as "include path" in your settings.

Comment: That {some path} is still `/opt/local/include/boost`. The version shown in that version.hpp is `#define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_54"`, which is indeed the version I have installed.